# SSRS report parameter needs multiple values

Tags: sql

[image]I am working on an SSRS report that has a parameter as 'Quarter1', 'Quarter2', 'Quarter3' and 'Quarter4' and I have a query that needs to take the user value and get data for that quarter and my query looks like this if Quarter 1 is selected.  am using VS 2010 BIDS for SSRS and SQL 2012 for database

```
Select 
CASE WHEN MONTH(DateGenerated) <= 3 THEN '1Q/'  
WHEN MONTH(DateGenerated) > 3 and MONTH(DateGenerated) <= 6 THEN '2Q/'
WHEN MONTH(DateGenerated) > 6 and MONTH(DateGenerated) <= 9 THEN '3Q/'
WHEN MONTH(DateGenerated) > 9 and MONTH(DateGenerated) <= 12 THEN '4Q/' END 
as GenDate, Notes, Equation

from SubTask 

 where Year(DateGenerated) = @year and MONTH(DateGenerated) in (@Quarter)
```

When doing it in SSRS, I am not able to give months (1, 2 and 3) as value to Quarter1. Is there a way that I am missing. Appreciate the help..

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter from SSRS will come over as a comma delimited string so we need a function to split the values.

For example, if your parameter is Quarter ... then your SQL would look like

```
Create Procedure xyz
@Quarter varchar(50) = null
as BEGIN

Select 
CASE WHEN MONTH(DateGenerated) <= 3 THEN '1Q/'  
WHEN MONTH(DateGenerated) > 3 and MONTH(DateGenerated) <= 6 THEN '2Q/'
WHEN MONTH(DateGenerated) > 6 and MONTH(DateGenerated) <= 9 THEN '3Q/'
WHEN MONTH(DateGenerated) > 9 and MONTH(DateGenerated) <= 12 THEN '4Q/' END 
as GenDate, Notes, Equation

from SubTask 

where Year(DateGenerated) = @year and MONTH(DateGenerated)
 in (Select Value From dbo.FNSplit(@Quarter,','))
```

And the function is ...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FnSplit]
(
@List nvarchar(max),
@SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(

Id int identity(1,1),
Value varchar(max)
) 
AS  
BEGIN
While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)
Begin 
Insert Into @RtnValue (value)
Select
Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1))) 
Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))
End 

Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)
Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))
Return
END

GO
```